# Application that recognizes default gestures and tells me about results

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, gestures

I need to check what gestures are available for certain touch pads and also find out what kind of information is available.

Is there some kind of application that simply recognizes gestures and prints out all relevant parameters for my test?

I am mainly interested in multi-finger gestures with 2-3 fingers, but also information about where a gesture was done (e. g. right border, left border) would be very helpful.

Target is going to be Windows 7 and 8 64 bit.

Comment: Are you trying to know the features supported by your touch pad ? 
If that's the case, I think its highly hardware dependent and no such Universal Tool exist, you need to look at the Manufacturer site or manual.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to find out. Hm... is it really HW-dependent, since Windows 8 does have gesture-recognition? I mean, it is different for Windows 7?? For Win 7, recogition would be provided by drivers or some other manufacturer-device?

Answer (score 2):

See the [ManipulationTracker Project](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/02/ManipulationTracker.zip) on this page:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/02/Windows-8-Touch-Events-Interactions.html

Not perfect, but has some good information.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is source only.. so after installing VS 2012 (full version, msdn) and.. getting a developer license, I tried compiling, fixed some dependency (v11.0 instead of v1.0 for the xaml csharp target) and.. it does not compile. Source is January 2012, and it seems to have been built with an early preview version that is not compatible. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's quite possible that it is no-longer compatible, I'm not able to check here. I'll leave this answer up though in case it's useful for anyone.

Comment: Well, it is not terribly difficult to fix as I found out: all events (the arguments to the functions) need to be renamed. Before each Event in the name, you have to add Routed (actually, if you do this correctly, you get Intellisense-feedback that things are getting better). So e. g. PointerEventArgs becomes PointerRoutedEventArgs.

Comment: Great, glad you've got something to work with now.

Comment: After some testing.. I have not found any TouchPads that this application supports. I think it is only for TouchScreens. Seems like those devices generate different events.